# How can I resolve non supported format error in aws cloudformation script

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cli

I am writing a cloudformation script which is supposed to pick the stack name, template body and parameter file from a .txt file for deployment. I would not want the yaml and json file to be edited during a new deployment instead the .txt file should be edited
The code is below

```
aws cloudformation create-stack --stack-name $(<stack_name.txt) --template-body 
file://$(<stack_template_file_name.txt) --parameters file://$(<stack_parameter_file_name.txt) capabilities "CAPABILITY_IAM" "CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM" --region=us-west-2
```

note: stack_name.txt contains the name to be used the stack, stack_template_file_name.txt contains the name of the template.yml file, stack_parameter_file_name.txt contains the name of the parameter.json file

when I type the command directly in the cli, the stack is deployed but when I copy it into create.sh and run ./create.sh I get the error below

```
`' doesn't match a supported format.`
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Somewhere there is `'`? Have you double checked your files?

Comment: A good way to debug this sort of thing is to add `echo` at the front of the command, to see what _would_ have been executed.

Comment: @Marcin I have checked the code more than twice but there is no where the character is found in the bash script.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein the command does not execute one after another, they form a single command passed to aws cli. Maybe I do not understand how I should echo. An example can help me debug it.

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to comment I found the same error from a different issue in the aws CLI.
`' doesn't match a supported format.`

When running:
`aws s3 cp file.txt s3://bucket-name/`

The issue was a malformed configuration in the
`~/.aws`  config folder.

Re-running the
`~/.aws configure` command didn't seem to fix the issue

however by inspecting the files in the
`~/.aws`  folder I was able to remove the random characters that were causing the issue.

Comment: Thank you for this. Just had the same problem. Delete the characters and now it's working

Comment: I am on MacOS and had the same issue while creating a s3 client using an existing configured aws profile. It seems that I cannot have space in the config settings. This gives me the error `region = us-east-1`, whiel this `region=us-east-1` does not.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was using Ubuntu Windows Linux Subsystem.

I was getting shell variables from `properties` file.

For e.g. My properties file `abc.properties`.

```
#VSRX
region=us-west-1
key_name=cft111
key_location=/var/cft111.pem
```

My Shell script `abc.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
action=$1
source ./abc.properties

if [[ $action == "create" ]]; then
  aws cloudformation deploy \
      --template-file abc.yml \
      --stack-name ${parent_stack_name} \
      --capabilities CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM \
      --region ${region} \
      --parameter-overrides KeyName=${key_name}
fi
```

I faced the similar issue and i tried echoing the command as well and i saw region parameter itself were invisible in echoed command.

**To my resolution : it was only formatting issue and i fixed it with below two commands.**

```
sed -i 's/\r$//' abc.sh

sed -i 's/\r$//' abc.properties
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out that it had to do with the EC2 environment, the exact command worked in a Windows and Ubuntu system.